# How to get this code to run in jsFiddle?

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

how to run this code in jsFiddle?
original code from Adam Khoury's site at http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1262

I've experimented and am able to get the button to show and the canvas outline but can not get the object to animate from left to right when the button is clicked.

Here is my attempt to get it to run in jsFiddle at...

http://jsfiddle.net/Tn8xC/

```
function draw(x,y){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,550,400);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect (x, y, 50, 50);
    ctx.restore(); 
    x += 1;
    var loopTimer = setTimeout('draw('+x+','+y+')',30);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That jsfiddle is coming back with an error 404 page.. can you just post the full link?

Comment: Please develop more your question

Comment: the question is well developed, jsfiddle is a place where you have 3 boxes for your code: html, css and javascript... the code on tutorial mixes them and he wants to know how to separate it

Comment: You should pay attention to the warnings the editor is giving you rather than trying to get around them by breaking the URL. Fiddles are certainly welcome, but you still need to include the important code snippets within the question text.

Comment: in fact there is an option indicating where the script should be placed in jsfiddle, it's currently `onload` in your fiddle, you have to change it to `wrap in <head>` and everything will be fine http://jsfiddle.net/Tn8xC/1/ (the options are on the left side bar in **Frameworks & Extensions**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle's default settings have JavaScript run `onLoad`, or after the HTML loads.

This works well for most cases, except for when you use an `on*` attribute to execute JS inline, because the JS hasn't loaded, so you can't access its variables and methods.

You need to change `onLoad`to `No wrap - in <head>` in the left sidebar at the top: this places your JS in `<script>` tags in the head. The head loads before everything else (whatever you put in the HTML area), so when you use the `onclick` attribute to reference your `draw()` function, it has already been defined.

You can also use `No wrap - in <body>` because the JS will still be placed before the rest of your HTML, but placing it in the `head` should serve you well in most cases.

Had you checked the console, you would have seen `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: draw`, which would have told you that your JS hadn't loaded before you tried to access `draw()`.

[image]

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/Tn8xC/5/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier True; I didn't think about that because I usually just throw it in the `head`.

Comment: @user1993348 I'm glad it helped! It would be great if you could [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grayed-out checkmark under the voting buttons so that we [both gain reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Thanks!

Comment: AstroCB, thanks for the tip on how 'accept' an answer... I've clicked the checkmark (and now I'm educated :)
King King had also contributed to my understanding of the OP but I can't see how to get his 'comment' to appear as a 'post' so I can also give him some credit as well.
Thanks again to both of you for your kind assistance.

Comment: @user1993348 If a user posts an answer in the comments ([which is perfectly acceptable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments)), you can't give credit because [comments are second-class citizens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260118/custom-reason-flags-open-for-over-two-weeks/260127#260127) here on SO. However, once you have enough reputation, you will gain the privilege [to vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), at which point you could upvote the comment. Although it awards no rep, it would show that the comment was useful.